# Remove a block of lines from xml file using xmllint

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmllint

I have **Test.xml** file, which has following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright XXXXXX -->
<services>
    <service>
        <ServiceName>service1</ServiceName>
        <ServiceId>100</ServiceId>
    </service>
    <service>
        <ServiceName>service2</ServiceName>
        <ServiceId>200</ServiceId>
    </service>
    <service>
        <ServiceName>service3</ServiceName>
        <ServiceId>300</ServiceId>
    </service>
</services>
```

Based on the service name, i have to remove the entire block of that service.

Suppose, ***service1*** is name i got as input, then following block should be removed from the xml.

```
<service>
    <ServiceName>service1</ServiceName>
    <ServiceId>100</ServiceId>
</service>
```

I can do this by using `awk/sed/grep`. But i should make use of **xmllint** or some other xml parsing utility here.

After research i could come closure to the output using below command. But, xml version and parent tags(services) are missing in the output.

```
xmllint --xpath "//services/service[ServiceName!='service1']" Test.xml
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT instead of XPath? If so check xsltproc command + XSL transform

Comment: @Bela Vizer, Yes i can use xsltproc. I will try that once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//service[ServiceName='service1']" test.xml
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright XXXXXX -->
<services>
  <service>
    <ServiceName>service2</ServiceName>
    <ServiceId>200</ServiceId>
  </service>
  <service>
    <ServiceName>service3</ServiceName>
    <ServiceId>300</ServiceId>
  </service>
</services>
```

---

- `//service[ServiceName='service1']` - *xpath* expression, selects `service` node which has child node `ServiceName` with value `service1`

---

To modify the file *"inplace"* - add `-L` option: `xmlstarlet ed -L ...`

Comment: Roman, Thanks for the reply. But, Sorry i can't use xmlstarlet.

Comment: @TejaswiBurgula, then, you've written a confusing description: *xmllint or **some other xml parsing utility***

Comment: Means, xmllint or some other utility like xsltproc. I have used xsltproc, its working fine. Thanks.